# immutable js modify ALL nested records

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Im trying to modify the 'completed' attributes of all Records of the OrderedMap. This is the OrderedMap:

```
const TodoItem = Record({text: '', completed: false});
let state = OrderedMap({'0': new TodoItem({text: 'First Item'})});
```

My current code is:

```
state.forEach((v,k) => {
  state = state.updateIn([k.toString(),'completed'], completed => true);
});
return state;
```

This works, but how?

Does it work because state is immutable and after the first iteration the forEach runs on the first state obj which is now anonymous?

Are there any other 'better' possibilities to modify attributes of all nested elements?

Comment: Where is confusion? state.forEach iterates by the OrderedMap, which assign during the forEach call, i.e. if you change state inside forEach (like add/remove Record) forEach will continue iteration with original state instance.

Comment: There is no real confusion, I was just asking myself if thats the best possible way in terms of performance to generate a new map for each update im doing to the immutable structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is -

```
state = state.map((todoItem)=>todoItem.set("completed", true));
```

Comment: Brilliant answer. Thanks!